# Entity Framework context menu missing from VS 2012 with EF 6 and EF 6 Tools installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

The Entity Framework context menu item is not available when I right click on a Model.edmx file in the VS 2012 Solution Explorer.  This is a c# project.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium Edition, Update 4.

I used the following steps:

1. Install Entity Framework 6.0.2 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 with no errors from this link:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762
2. Create new C# ASP.Net Web Form Application.
3. Install the Entity Framework 6.0.2 package using NuGet.
4. Add new ADO.NET Entity Data Model and added a few entities to it.
5. Build the solution.
6. Right-click on Model.edmx file in Solution Explorer and there is no Entity Framework menu item.

I have tried re-running the Entity Framework Tools msi and selecting the repair option, but that didn't help.

the Extensions and Updates tool does not list "Entity Framework 6.0.2 Tools" among my installed extensions, but I'm not sure I'm supposed to since I did not install it using the Extensions and Updates tool.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework context menu is not part of Entity Framework tooling but a part of EF Power Tools. You need to download and install EF Power Tools Beta 4.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me what the EF Tooling is?  I thought it was the RTM version of "EF Power Tools Beta 4".

Comment: The tooling is the EF Designer - allows create and manipulate the edmx file that describes your model and also create a database from the model. EF Designer is currently used for Database First and Model First flows. Power Tools are additional tools useful for CodeFirst apps.

Comment: I have a website solution, asp.net 4.6 C# EF6, but the power tools menu is not visible when I right click on the EDMX. I have some fear that there is a bug that doesn't display it on website projects.